# How do I call a method present in root view controller from my second view controller?

Tags: iphone

when iam trying to call

```
rootviewcontroller *rootview=[rootviewcontroller alloc];
[rootview methodname];
```

is showing warning  "root view controller may not respond"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that "methodname" is not a "public" (*) method of your rootviewcontroller class.

You need something like

```
@interface rootviewcontroller : baseclass {
  - (void) methodname;
}
```

At the moment, while rootviewcontroller *might* respond to the message called "methodname", the compiler can't see that it does (because you've not told it so through the above).

(*) Objective-C methods are all public in way C++/Java people would understand the term. I suppose I should really say "is not a method declared in the `@interface` of the class".